# Safari doesn't respect lang attribute for Greek locale for text-transform:uppercase

Tags: html, safari, webkit, locale, lang

Safari doesn't respect lang attribute for Greek locale for `text-transform: uppercase;` css rule,
but it works perfectly for Chrome

For string with all uppercased letters accent should be removed

But if we make it by JavaScript everything works fine for both

`"Πρόκριση".toLocaleUpperCase('el') // "ΠΡΟΚΡΙΣΗ"`

Is there exists any another workaround or solution?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <style>
      p {
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p lang="el">Πρόκριση</p>
    <p>Πρόκριση</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

| Chrome | Safari |
| --- | --- |
| [image: First] | [image: row] |